# Codeigniter join multiple tables with where clauses

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have four tables that I need to join together, with one of those tables having two different records I need to grab. The `guild` and `party` tables I'm getting the name of those so that I can display the name instead of ID to the user, and the `charlog` table has the char_id's creation date and last login date that I want to show as well. Here are the tables:

`char` table:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| char_id    | name    | guild_id    | party_id    |
|---------------------------------------------------
| 150000     | char1   | 3           | 3           |
| 150001     | char2   | 2           | (NULL)      |
| 150002     | char3   | (NULL)      | 1           |
| 150003     | char4   | 1           | 2           |
----------------------------------------------------
```

`guild` table:

```
-------------------------
| guild_id   | name     |
-------------------------
| 1          | guild_1  |
| 2          | guild_2  |
| 3          | guild_3  |
-------------------------
```

`party` table:

```
-------------------------
| party_id   | name     |
-------------------------
| 1          | party_1  |
| 2          | party_2  |
| 3          | party_3  |
-------------------------
```

`charlog` table:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| time                 | char_id   | char_msg      |
----------------------------------------------------
| 2015-02-14 06:45:32  | 150000    | make new char |
| 2015-02-14 06:45:58  | 150000    | char select   |
| 2015-02-15 12:32:19  | 150001    | make new char |
| 2015-02-15 16:54:01  | 150000    | char select   |
| 2015-02-15 19:23:54  | 150001    | char select   |
| 2015-02-16 01:32:13  | 150002    | make new char |
| 2015-02-16 01:33:01  | 150003    | make new char |
| 2015-02-16 04:45:43  | 150000    | char select   |
| 2015-02-16 07:43:22  | 150003    | char select   |
----------------------------------------------------
```

As mentioned, I need to get the `make new char` entry from the `charlog` table to display when the character was created and as well the LAST (by date) `char select` entry to display when the character was played, all of this with one single char_id.

All in all, I'd be looking for a table that looks like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| char_id    | name     | guild_id | guild_name | party_id | party_name | create_time         | lastlogin_time      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 150000     | char1    | 3        | guild_3    | 3        | party_3    | 2015-02-14 06:45:32 | 2015-02-16 04:45:43 |
```

I'm using the following active record lines in Codeigniter to attempt to get the data I need. It returns the create_date correctly but the lastlogin_time is not returned (it's blank):

```
function get_char_info($cid) {
    $this->db->select('char.*,guild.guild_id,guild.name AS guild_name,party.party_id,party.name AS party_name,charlog1.time AS create_time,charlog2.time AS lastlogin_time');
    $this->db->from('char');
    $this->db->where('char.char_id', $cid);
    $this->db->join('guild', 'char.guild_id = guild.guild_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('party', 'char.party_id = party.party_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('charlog AS charlog1', 'char.char_id = charlog1.char_id AND charlog1.char_msg = "make new char"', 'left');
    $this->db->join('charlog AS charlog2', 'char.char_id = charlog2.char_id AND charlog2.char_msg = (SELECT max(charlog.time) FROM charlog WHERE char_msg = "char select")', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

As mentioned, the guild_name, party_name and create_time come through correctly, but the lastlogin_time is blank, no error.

I've tried jumbling some things around in the active record clauses but can't get the lastlogin_time to show. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join on your subquery is not correct :

It should be `charlog2.time = (SELECT....)` not `charlog2.char_msg = (SELECT....)`